# inject http or service inside static

Tags: angular, typescript

I am making validation on angular2 through GlobalValidaitor.ts  file i put on it all extra method that i need as following

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Api } from '../providers/api';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


export class GlobalValidator {


   constructor(public Api: Api) {

  }



  public  static checkEmailExisit(control: FormControl): any {
     return new Promise(resolve => {

      //Fake a slow response from server

      let  senddata: {email?: string} = {
        email : control.value
      };


      let seq = this.Api.post('phones/offers', senddata).share() ;
    seq
     .map(res => res.json())
     .subscribe(res => {
     resolve(res);
     });

    });

  }



  static mailFormat(control: FormControl): any {

    var EMAIL_REGEXP = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/i;

    if (control.value != "" && (control.value.length <= 5 || !EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value))) {
        return { "incorrectMailFormat": true };
    }

    return null;
}




}
```

and as its a static don't consider API
i will be thankful to help in angular 2 not the last version it shall be usage of HTTP_PROVIDER and inject directly onside the function 
but for the last version of angular it don't work i event cant import HTTP_PROVIDER

Comment: `this` would refer to the class itself, if anything, inside a static member. There's no way it could possibly have access to `Api`.

Comment: i think  its possible to inject http as question i was not insist on API

Comment: How about punctuating your sentences?

Comment: inject http or service inside static this the title of question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to not use static at all.

Remove static and pass the validator like

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [GlobalValidator],
})
```

```
constructor(private globalValidator:GlobalValidator) {}
  ... 
  myEmail: [globalValidator.emailExists.bind(globalValidator)]
  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

i was possible to inject http inside static i do it as following

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Headers, XHRBackend, ConnectionBackend, BrowserXhr, ResponseOptions, XSRFStrategy, BaseResponseOptions, CookieXSRFStrategy, RequestOptions, BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';



export class GlobalValidator extends CookieXSRFStrategy{



   static checkUserEmail(control: FormControl): any {
    let data :any ;
     let http =  ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
             Http, BrowserXhr,
             { provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: XHRBackend },
             { provide: ResponseOptions, useClass: BaseResponseOptions },
             { provide: XSRFStrategy, useClass: GlobalValidator },
             { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions }
           ]).get(Http);


    var body = 'email='+control.value;
     var headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    let reques=  http
       .post('http://www.etc.cc/ChekEmail',
         body, {
           headers: headers
         }).share() ;


      reques   .map(res => res.json())
         .subscribe(res => {
           console.error('connected :', res.ishere);


         }, err => {
             console.error('ERROR in connection :',  JSON.stringify(err));
           });

  }
```

any way thanks for trying help

Comment: That is not dependency injection. It is basically the service locator pattern. Why use static methods for this at all? You can  just as well use free standing functions for this purpose. A class simply adds complexity for zero value in this case.

Comment: Basically this follows along from a really terrible example that was given early on, perhaps by some ridiculous starter kit, and I've seen it in a code base I worked on.

Comment: thanks a lot for contribute to question but do you have a better solution ?

Comment: Sure, use a regular class with instance methods or freestanding functions. Gunter's answer is suggestive of a good approach.

Comment: thanks i already do but i don't understand main problem on injection HTTP inside the static function can you please explain why we shall not ?

Comment: A class is a value. Defining it instantiates it. How can you inject something if the instance, which is the class itself, has already been created? Don't let the keyword `class` fool you, these are nothing like C++, C#, Java, Scala, or Dart classes and the sooner you realize that the better your programs will become.